# How to render a Draft.js block as a React Component with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-component, draftjs

I use Draft.js for users to create blogposts, and I save the editor state on my database as json.

To display the blogpost as HTML to users, I use `draftjs-to-html` to convert the state into HTML.

The library display the image correct to the users, but I need those images to be optimized with Next/Image component.

If I make a custom renderer to instead of returning the `<img>` tag return the `<Image />` tag from Next, at the HTML it's returned `[Object object]` and not the processed HTML.

So I tried to use the`renderToString` from `react-dom/server` like this: `renderToString(<Image .../>)` but I receive a plain javascript at the HTML, and not the expected result.

So in a nut shell what I need is to create a custom renderer that accepts a React component as a return.

I have also tried the `draft-js-export-html` library, but I have similar results.